# Racket: Contract violation, (and/c list? (not/c empty?)) expected given: '()?

Tags: racket

I am searching for a long(长) time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

what i am write is The function firsts takes one argument, a list, which is either a null list or contains only non-empty lists. It builds another list composed of the first S-expression of each
internal list.
and my code is as follows:

```
(define (first l)
    (cond
        [(null? l) l]
        [(null? (car l)) (cons '() (first (cdr l)))]
    )
)
```

but when i call `(first '(()))`,it goes out this error.i hava no idea about this.Thanks in advance.

Wanted to know if it's good practice to do that and what would(将) be the best way to do that?

Comment: If the function is supposed to be *guaranteed* to only be given empty lists, or non-empty lists of non-empty lists, `'(())` is not a meaningful test case. (And `(null? (car l))` can never be true.)

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to make the call `(first '(()))`, then your function should not assume that all elements of the input list are *nonempty* lists. In this case, when traversing the input list, your function must ignore those elements for which function `(car lst)` is not defined. Also, since `(first lst)` is a predefined function in Racket, it would be better to use another name for your function, for example `cars`.

```lisp
(define (cars lst)
  (cond [(empty? lst) lst]
        [(pair? (car lst)) (cons (caar lst) (cars (cdr lst)))] ; process first element
        [else (cars (cdr lst))]))                              ; ignore first element
```

Note that `(pair? (car lst))` is used to filter relevant elements of the input list, and `(caar lst)`, that is equivalent to `(car (car lst))`, is used to get the first element of the first list of `lst`.

Examples:

```
> (cars '((a b) (c) (d e f))) 
'(a c d)

> (cars '((a b c) () (d e f)))
'(a d)

> (cars '((a) (b c) d (e f)))
'(a b e)
```

**REMARK** If the input list really only contains nonempty lists, you can get the desired result using function [map](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._map%29%29), as follows:

```lisp
> (map car '((a b) (c) (d e f) (g h))) 
'(a c d g)
```